# Exclude protected & private methods from call graphs Doxygen Eclox

Tags: python, eclipse, doxygen

First I'm going to describe my configuration. I'm using Eclipse with the plugin Eclox. The language of the code is Python (3.5).

My goal is generate documentation of a proyect with Doxygen. To use doxygen with Python I have installed doxypypy extensión.

I get correctly the documentation. The problem is that I have disabled private and protected in the doxygen's file but in the call's graph still appears the private and protected functions. How could I dissable private and protected functions in the diagrams made by dot?

Edit 2 :  Doxygen version : 1.8.11

Edit 1 :  I show some example of protected and private method:

Private method

```
    def __plotData(self,x_axis,data):
    """
    @brief Plot the data
    @param[in] x_axis : X axis
    @param[in] data: Y axis
    """
    plt.figure()
    plt.stem(x_axis / 1e6, data, use_line_collection = True)
    plt.grid()
    plt.draw()
    plt.close()
    plt.pause(0.01)
```

- Now a protected method :

  ```
  def _zplane(p,filename=None):

  """
  @brief Plot the poles of a polinomy

  @param[in] p : Poles of the polinomy

  @param[in] filename : Output File.

  """

  #Plot the poles given the roots
  # get a figure/plot

  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  # create the unit circle

  uc = patches.Circle((0,0), radius=1, fill=False,

                      color='black', ls='dashed')

  ax.add_patch(uc)

  # Get the poles and zeros
  # Plot the poles and set marker properties

  t2 = plt.plot(p.real, p.imag, 'rx', ms=10)

  plt.setp( t2, markersize=12.0, markeredgewidth=3.0,

            markeredgecolor='r', markerfacecolor='r')

  ax.spines['left'].set_position('center')

  ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('center')

  ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

  ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

  # set the ticks

  r = 1.5; plt.axis('scaled'); plt.axis([-r, r, -r, r])

  ticks = [-1, -.5, .5, 1]; plt.xticks(ticks); plt.yticks(ticks)
  plt.show()
  ```

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give a small example with private and protected members where you see the problem?

Comment: Show us the source and the result! What you describe is strange since Python does not have private or protected methods. It has only a naming convention for methods and attributes that should be considered private.

Comment: Missing doxygen version. Diminish empty lines in your question. Also make examples a bit completer as there are no calls to the mentioned functions.

Comment: perhaps because in python private and protected do not really exist, all is public, the use of _ is just a convention and nothing more

Comment: Version 1.8.11 is a bit old, the current version is 1.8.18. In the code I see some code that says that methods and variables starting with a `_` are private except in case of methods when its name starts and ends with `__` in that case it will be private. As the name is just a convention is there an authoritative document stating the use of `_`, `__` etc.? Also have a look at the doxygen commands `\private` and `\protected`.